# symfony3 : query_builder search by boolean field

Tags: doctrine, symfony, query-builder

I have a form search and i'd like to select data by boolean field. The problem is that if the select choice **has false value (0)**  the query returns all data but if selected choice **has true value (1)** the query is correct.

In the formTye:

```
            ->add('publier', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Publier',
            'choices' => array('oui' => '1', 'non' => '0'),
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')
        ));
```

and in the query_builder

```
        if (!empty($publier)) {
        $qb->andWhere('a.publier = :publier')
            ->setParameter('publier', $publier  );
    }
```

if I remove this test : **if (!empty($publier)) {**   and I select a false choice the returned data is correct but I can't remove this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed

```
 if (!empty($publier))
```

by

```
if (null !== $publier )
```

and it works fine now

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. [The manual](https://secure.php.net/empty) gives you a list of values which are considered empty. `false` is one of them

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question clearly, but if it's a boolean you want, you should try this:

```
->add('publier', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'required' => false,
    'label' => 'Publier',
    'choices' => array(
        'oui' => true,
        'non' => false
    ),
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => false,
    'attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')
));
```

Not sure if it will work. The way you have it with '1' and '0', those are strings (not integers).

Comment: I have changed   **if (!empty($publier))**  by **if (null !== $publier )** and it works fine now